# How to compare current serial port data with the previous data in c#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I want to compare my serial port data I want it to follow the correct sequence to make it as a pass result. It will be like if Batt Level= High then next result if Ac = Medium then it will be a pass result but if  Ac =High then the next result is Batt Level = Low it will fail. Because of the serial data keep running every second, how to catch the previous result and compare with the incoming result?

The condition will be like this:

Batt Level : High

Batt Level : High
Batt Level : Mid
Result = Pass

Batt Level : High
Batt Level : High
Batt Level : Low
Result = Fail

Below code is what I am trying to do but I think this method is not accurate:

```
SerialPort sp = serialPort1;

string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

dataIn = indata;
        string serialdata = indata.Replace("\n\r", "");

      if (serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : High"))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if ((serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : High")) || 
        (serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : Mid")))
                {
                Battresult.Text = "PASS";
                }

            else 
                {
                Battresult.Text = "FAIL";
            }
        }
        else if (serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : Mid"))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if ((serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : Mid")) || (serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : Low")))
                {
                Battresult.Text = "PASS";
                }

            else 
            {
                Battresult.Text = "FAIL";
            }
        }
```

Comment: take a `List<string>` and store the incoming data. then iterate over the collection and compare. Can you please post the entire method where this code is situated? the context of the calling site is very important

Comment: i have edited my code and question.tq

Comment: you need to compare 2 conseccutive readings, am I right? so you need to store the previous reading. This is actually what you are doing in this line: `dataIn = indata;`. This should be at the end of your code. And your first if condition should check the previous reading: `if (dataIn != null && dataIn.Contains("Batt Level : High"))`

Comment: Hi, is that something like this?

  if (dataIn != null && dataIn.Contains("Batt Level : High"))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if ((serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : High")) || (serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : Mid")))
                    {
                    BattResult.Text = "PASS";
                    }

                else 
                    {
                    BattResult.Text = "FAIL";
                }
            }

Comment: have you tried it out? does it work? only you can tell :)

Comment: I have tried it but the results were not accurate .

low to high = pass , not true
medium to medium = pass ,true

Answer (score 0):

is that something like this?

```
     if (dataIn != null && dataIn.Contains("Batt Level : High"))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if ((serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : High")) || 
     (serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : Mid")))
                {
                BattResult.Text = "PASS";
                }

            else 
                {
                BattResult.Text = "FAIL";
            }
        }

      else if (dataIn != null && dataIn.Contains("Batt Level : Medium"))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if ((serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : Mid")) || 
           (serialdata.Contains("Batt Level : Low")))
                {
                BattResult.Text = "PASS";
                }

            else 
            {
                BattResult.Text = "FAIL";
            }
        }


        dataIn = indata;
```